# Retrieve SQL Records Based on Past Date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have some database records, and one of the columns contains the date the record was added (called COMP_DATE).

I need to make a query, that will run each day, which selects records whose COMP_DATE is exactly n years, 11 months, and 15 days ago (within a 24 hour window). (I.E. 15 days before n years ago).

What would be the best way of doing this? Should I just subtract (n*356 - 15 days)? How would I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your reply to @theglauber, well then what exactly do you consider to be n years, 11 months and 15 days ago? Are you worried about leap years? Do you want to skip the leap year day last year, and skip two days if it's more than 4 years ago (since two leap years will have happened)? Perhaps you could show a few problematic dates, what date you expect to return on those dates, and what queries you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way will be to do it the other way around to obtain n years 11 months and 15 days ago
Remove n+1 years and add 15 days, you'll have the less room for errors

```
DECLARE @n as INT=<your value here>;

SELECT *
FROM   records
WHERE  comp_date BETWEEN Dateadd(DAY, 15, Dateadd(YEAR, -@n-1, Getdate()))
   AND Dateadd(DAY, 16, Dateadd(YEAR, -@n-1, Getdate()));
```

Hope that helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are functions to do date arythmetic. For example, [Dateadd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

(Assuming this is Microsoft SQL Server based on the question's tags.)

Comment: I'm aware of these functions, but unsure if doing day subraction would be the best approach, because a year is not exactly 365 days, and my search could go back as far as 6 years, which puts it off by more than a day. And if I do Year / Month subtraction, I might miss leap days, or the last day of the months that have 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from records where
comp_date = dateadd(year,-n,dateadd(month,-11,dateadd(days, -15, GetDate())));
```

*assumimg comp_date is of type Date.

Answer (score 0):

if comp_date is datetime column type, you'll want to search on a range (a 24 hour range).  Also, if you are looking for 15 days before n years ago, the query should look like this:

```
select * from records where
comp_date >= dateadd(year,-n,dateadd(day, -15, getdate()))
and comp_date < dateadd(year,-n,dateadd(day, -14, getdate()));
```

If indeed you are wanting n years 11 months and 15 days ago, use WOPRs answer.